# Android app runs fast on the emulator but very slow on the phone

Tags: android, android-emulator

I built an X and O game on Android Studio when I run the app on the emulator it operates normally but when I run it on the phone it is very slow, I built before a similar app called Tick tac toe it has the same code and logic but different images only, but it runs fast on both my phone and the emulator, I suspected that the size of the X and O images is huge so the game runs slow but when I checked the sizes it has nearly similar sizes with the Tick tac toe I don't know why the game is slow even it is very simple please help.

the code:

Firstly the Tick tac toe:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        android:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:rowCount="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="0"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="1"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="2"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="3"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="4"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="5"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="6"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="7"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView11"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="8"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="2" />
    </GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/playAgainLayout"
        android:layout_width="189dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#46d65e"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/gridLayout"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.011"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/winnerMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/playAgainButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="playAgain"
            android:text="Play Again" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

JAVA

```
package com.k_pc.tick_tac_toe;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // 0 = yellow, 1 = red;
    int activePlayer = 0;

    // 2 means unplayed
    int [] gameState= {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};

    int [] [] winningPositions = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, {0,4,8}, {2,4,6}};

    public void dropIn (View view){

        ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;

        System.out.println(counter.getTag().toString());

        int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());

        if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2) {

            gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;

            counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);

            if (activePlayer == 0) {
                counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                activePlayer = 1;
            } else {
                counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
                activePlayer = 0;
            }

            counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).rotation(360f).setDuration(500);

            for (int [] winningPosition : winningPositions){
                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] &&
                        gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
                        gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2){

                    //Someone has won

                    String winner = "Red";

                    if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 0){

                        winner = "Yellow";
                    }



                    TextView winnerMeassage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);
                    winnerMeassage.setText(winner + " has won!");

                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);

                    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }

        }

    }

    public void playAgain (View view){

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);

        layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        // 0 = yellow, 1 = red;
        activePlayer = 0;

        // 2 means unplayed
        for (int i = 0 ; i < gameState.length ; i++){
            gameState[i] = 2;
        }

        // setting all the images source to nothing


        GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);




        for(int i = 0 ; i<gridLayout.getChildCount() ; i++){

            ((ImageView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Images of Tick tac toe:
1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/19lJa.jpg
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZtvx.jpg
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u1Lz.jpg

Secondly the X and O:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="115dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="115dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="115dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="115dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="115dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="4" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="115dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="5"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="115dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="6"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="115dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="7"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="115dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="8"/>
    </GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/playAgainLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#4be433"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/winnerMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="playAgain"
            android:text="PLAY AGAIN" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

JAVA

```
    package com.k_pc.xando;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // 0 = x, 1 = o
    int activePlayer = 0;

    // 2 means unplayed
    int [] gameState ={2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};

    int [] [] winningPositions = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, {0,4,8}, {2,4,6}};

    public void dropIn (View view){

        ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;

        System.out.println("Tag: "+counter.getTag().toString());

        counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);

        int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());

        if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2) {

            gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;

            if (activePlayer == 0) {
                counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
                activePlayer = 1;
            } else {
                counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
                activePlayer = 0;
            }
        }
        counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).rotation(720).setDuration(500);

        for (int [] winningPosition : winningPositions){
            if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] &&
                    gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
                    gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2){

                //Someone has won

                String winner = "O";

                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 0){

                    winner = "X";
                }

                TextView winnerMeassage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);
                winnerMeassage.setText(winner + " has won!");

                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);

                layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }

        int played = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < gameState.length; i++){
            if (gameState[i] != 2){
                played++;
            }
        }
        if(played == gameState.length){
            TextView winnerMeassage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);
            winnerMeassage.setText("No one has won!");

            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);
            layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }


    public void playAgain (View view){

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);

        layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        // 0 = yellow, 1 = red;
        activePlayer = 0;

        // 2 means unplayed
        for (int i = 0 ; i < gameState.length ; i++){
            gameState[i] = 2;
        }

        // setting all the images source to nothing


        GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);




        for(int i = 0 ; i<gridLayout.getChildCount() ; i++){

            ((ImageView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

The images for X and O:
 1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/19lJa.jpg
 2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qqcw.jpg
 3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAZTq.jpg

I don't think the code will help because both have the same code but one only is faster than the other, the problem may be in the images.

Here is a video showing the two apps and how slow the X and O compared to Tick tac toe.

https://vimeo.com/291295377

Comment: How about some image asset examples, code, device model, etc?

Comment: Might be cuz your config of emulator is higher than your phone

Comment: I updated the question